# How to edit HTML value if its in a class that cointains a specific href with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Well I am learning javascript and I am trying to write a function which would look `if(href.contains(1234567)` and change `class="price"` value to any number.

I tried googling but I cant seem to find an answer to this

```
<div class="product-info">
      <a href="https:someUrl.com/1234567">
        <div class="title">
          Some Sweet Title
        </div>
      </a>
      <div class="price">
        ValueHereNeedsToBeAdded
      </div>
    </div>
```

I expect `class="price"` value to be changed to some number

Comment: You can use the [attribute contains selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Attribute_selectors) with [next](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

Comment: So select the link, read the href, check for the number..... What did you try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `a[href*=1234567]+.price` selector to do it.

`a[href*=1234567]` select all `<a>` elements that have a href attribute value containing "1234567" and `+.price` select element has class price placed immediately after that `a[href*=1234567]`.

Demo:

```js
$('a[href*=1234567]+.price').text(123456)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-info">
      <a href="https:someUrl.com/1234567">
        <div class="title">
          Some Sweet Title
        </div></a>
      <div class="price">
        ValueHereNeedsToBeAdded
      </div>
    </div>
     <a href="https:someUrl.com/test">
     </a>
     <div class="price">
        ValueNoNeedsToBeAddedHere
      </div>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. Its hard to wrap my head around javascript and jquarry as I am just starting!

Answer (score 0):

You can do without jquery :-

```
<div class="product-info">
      <a href="https:someUrl.com/1234567" id="link_id" onclick="check(this.href)">
        <div class="title">
          Some Sweet Title
        </div></a>
      <div class="price" id="setvalue">
        ValueHereNeedsToBeAdded
      </div>
    </div>


function check()
    {
    event.preventDefault();
    var href = document.getElementById("link_id").getAttribute("href");
        if(href.includes(1234567))
        {
        document.getElementById('setvalue').innerHTML = '1313133';
        }
    }
```

Comment: OP is asking to change the text of the element, not the class.

Answer (score 0):

A solution with jQuery:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str = $('#link').attr('href');
  if (str.indexOf("1234567") >= 0){
  
     var x = document.getElementsByClassName("price");
     var y = x[0];

     y.classList.add('myClass');
     y.classList.remove('price');
     y.innerHTML = "123456"    
  }
}

myFunction();
```

```css
.myClass{
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-info">
      <a id="link" href="https:someUrl.com/1234567">
        <div class="title">
          Some Sweet Title
        </div>
      </a>
      <div class="price">
        ValueHereNeedsToBeAdded
      </div>
 </div>
```